# Javascript sort function nor working in Safari/iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, sorting, safari

I've looked through most of the previous asked questions about this topic, but still can't get mine to work.

I have this code, which sorts an array of objects:

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  var dateA=new Date(a.created_time), dateB=new Date(b.created_time)
  return (dateB > dateA) ? 1 : (dateB < dateA) ? -1 : 0;
});
```

It works fine in FF and Chrome (desktop), but fails in Safari(desktop/iphone) and Chrome(iphone)

The array of objects is an AJAX call from Facebook, getting a wall feed, and I want to sort by created_time.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That didn't work in any browser!?

Comment: is `a.created_time` a time as number in milliseconds like `1370249076800` ?

Comment: Nope, it's like this: '2013-06-03T08:05:06+0000'

Comment: Well then, its because of the browsers `Date` constructor implemented differently. It seems like mobile chrome on iphone and safari aren't able to parse a string like `2013-06-03T08:05:06+0000` you would need to parse the string on your own and create a new Date of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Safari and the other mentioned Browser's (chrome on iphone) can't parse the input String you pass to the constructor. Which results in an `Invalid Date` which primitives value is `NaN`

Hence, the sort function does not work as inteded, comparing `return (NaN > NaN) ? 1 : (NaN < NaN) ? -1 : 0;`, resulting in `return 0`

To work around this, with a minimum of parsing effort, i thought of just splitting the String
by `-|:|T|\+`. And use The date parts on their own to construc a `new Date`

*Note: Unfortunetaly sth like var d = Date.apply([year,month,...]) is not possible*

So here is a sort function which works for me on Safari

```
var dates = [{
        name: "A",
        created_time: '2013-06-05T08:05:06+0000'
    }, {
        name: "B",
        created_time: '2013-06-03T10:05:06+0000'
    }, {
        name: "C",
        created_time: '2013-06-03T01:05:06+0000'
    }
];

var sorted = dates.sort(function (a, b) {
        var reg = /-|:|T|\+/; //The regex on which matches the string should be split (any used delimiter) -> could also be written like /[.:T\+]/
        var parsed = [ //an array which holds the date parts for a and b
            a.created_time.split(reg), //Split the datestring by the regex to get an array like [Year,Month,Day,Hour,...]
            b.created_time.split(reg)
        ];
        var dates = [ //Create an array of dates for a and b
            new Date(parsed[0][0], parsed[0][1], parsed[0][2], parsed[0][3], parsed[0][4], parsed[0][5]),//Constructs an date of the above parsed parts (Year,Month...
            new Date(parsed[1][0], parsed[1][1], parsed[1][2], parsed[1][3], parsed[1][4], parsed[1][5])
        ];
        return dates[0] - dates[1]; //Returns the difference between the date (if b > a then a - b < 0)
    });
```

Which gives the output:

```
console.log(sorted);
/*
[{
        "created_time": "2013-06-03T01:05:06+0000",
        "name": "C"
    }, {
        "created_time": "2013-06-03T10:05:06+0000",
        "name": "B"
    }, {
        "created_time": "2013-06-05T08:05:06+0000",
        "name": "A"
    }
]
*/
```

**Demo on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/elotuc/1/edit)**

Comment: Well I wouldn't have come up with that on my own, and I'm still trying to grasp exactly what you're doing. But it works :) - Thank you very much!

Comment: @afcdesign You're welcome =) 

I've commented the code to make it more comprehensible. If you have any question, just put a comment.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Thank you, I have spent far to much time banging my head against my desk before finding this post.

Comment: I thought momentJs would work for me, but no.  This answer did it!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but I just ran into the same problem and have a different solution.

If you are willing/able to add moment.js to your project, this stuff is completely straightforward. Moment handles all kinds of date weirdness that different browsers throw up... this works in every browser I've tested so far.

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = new moment(a.created_time);
  b = new moment(b.created_time);
  return a < b ? -1 : 1; // ascending order
});
```