# Array.sort random function does not works in iPhone's Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, sorting, safari

Here is my code:

```
var array = 'BCDFGA'.split('');

var sorted = array.sort(function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(sorted)); // B, C, D, F, G, A
```

See it on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hemuquqidi/1/edit)

What I'm doing wrong?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892525/javascript-sort-function-nor-working-in-safari-iphone), but I totally do not understand why it is not working with random.

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? Examples of incorrect behaviors please.

Comment: @Zaph open it in iPhone's Safari. It does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.filtercolumn1=[];     
$scope.filtercolumn1.sort(function(a,b){
                    var nameA = a.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
                    var nameB = b.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
                    if (nameA < nameB) {
                    return -1;
                    }
                    if (nameA > nameB) {
                    return 1;
                    }

                    // names must be equal
                    return 0;
                })


this is done using angular + javascript  you can refer the logic from here
```